# Convert C# unsafe code to its VB.NET equivalent

Tags: c#, vb.net, pointers, bitmap, code-translation

Given the limitations of VB.NET, how do I get the VB code to successfully function as closely as possible to this C# code?:

```
// ImageData -> Bitmap (unsafe)
public static unsafe Bitmap ToBitmap(this ImageData bitmap)
{
    fixed(byte* = bitmap.Data)
    {
        return new Bitmap(bitmap.ImageSize.Width, bitmap.ImageSize.Height, bitmap.Stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(bitmap.Data));
    }
}
```

Since there is no pointer support in VB.NET, I know I need to fall back to the .NET framework interoperability support functions from the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class, but I'm not exactly sure how to match the same functionality of that C# code and without hindering (as far as possible due the VB.NET limitations) the processing speed of pointers usage.

Note: the C# code was took from [here](https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit#usage-details).

Comment: Do you really need to convert it? VB.Net can consume a class library written in C#.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. I'm aware of that. I honestly prefer to be able to convert it to VB.NET.

Comment: This is used to fix a byte array in memory to perform the operation without declaring a byte array container (`byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Stride * data.Height]`). You can do that using `Marshal.Copy()`, which is commonly called when the `BitmapData` of an Image is copied back to the original source using the `Scan0` pointer. This can be done using unsafe pointers or using the `Marshal` methods. Whether you need to pin the block (to avoid GC collection) I cannot say, I don't know what `ImageData` is (just a byte array?). BTW, that code is missing the identifier.

Comment: probably you could just use the .Net [Unsafe Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe?view=net-5.0), it's for cases like that i think