# Ignore compiler error BC30668: 'Types with embedded references are not supported in this version of your compiler'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.2, and when I try to compile a code written in VB.NET on which I declared a function whose parameter with name "ImageData" is a class from a 3rd party library written in C#, and that "ImageData" class expose a public property of type `System.Span`, I get the next compiler error:

> Error BC30668 'ImageData' is obsolete:
> 'Types with embedded references are not supported in this version of your compiler.'.

After a little research it seems this is **[a non-sense decision by design](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/297)**:

> They have confirmed that this behavior is by design. I don't understand
> why they are not intend to let stack-only structures consumable in VB
> when c# is able to define them. Maybe they thought ref structs are
> similar to unsafe types. So, in most cases, VB developers may not
> hurry to consume these types. But this assumption does not make sense,
> because ref structs are not unsafe codes. They can be defined or be
> used in C# 7.2 outside of the unsafe context, why can't we just
> consume them in VB?
>
> Both System.Span(Of T) and System.ReadOnlySpan(Of T) are important new
> APIs for .NET developers who care about both performance and type
> safety. We should feel natural when using them, rather than seeing the
> annoying BC30668 compilation error.

Is there any workaround to ignore this compiler error so I can compile my code under VBNET?.

Comment: Afaik there is no way to suppress compiler error.

Comment: Surrender :) You'll find more and more of these *situations* in the future. Build that code in a C# Project in the same Solution that contains your VB.Net Project. As you may probably know, there are no scheduled updates / *upgrades* to VB.Net.

Comment: @Jimi when there is no way, there is no way. What bothers me is that I had already managed to adapt the c# unsafe code with the indications you gave me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072137/convert-c-sharp-unsafe-code-to-its-vb-net-equivalent but if I can't compile it due this... I only can surrender. Thanks.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Yeah, surrender for this special case, but keep up the fight! ;-) I think it is very bad for the .NET community in general but also for C# if VB.NET dies out. This concurrency has improved both languages a lot. VB has a lot of features that are just not possible to convert to C# (Interface-Innerinterfaces and Interface-Innerclasses, extension methods byRef, the whole beauty of XML handling etc. and tiny little comfort things like overwriting the iterator variable - I just miss these things in C#, and when I mentioned these things in a C# language forum, I get flamed.)

Comment: @All out there: Do you think we can find enough resources to start guerilla-implementing theses language features in a community-owned roslyn branch of the VB-compiler?